# OnXMSException listener not invoked when network disconnected

Tags: ibm-mq, xms

I'm using IBM XMS v 9.0 .NET C# client library to connect IBM MQ. 
Once connection are established, assigned MessageListener and OnXMSException. 
Have set XMSC_WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT = 30.

We are getting messages on MessageListener and everything works fine.

When I disconnect the network after successful connection, I won’t get any exception delivered to OnXMSException listener method.

My intension is, if MQ connection is no longer valid / active , I should get back error ASAP, so that I can establish a new connection quickly to start reading the messages to avoid queue backlog.

Is XMSC_WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT, is the right one ? or any other setting exist for this?

I am trying network disconnect because sometimes we have noted that even when MQ connection in not active on MQ server, the client would get no CONNECTION BROKEN error. But sometime it works.)

Comment: Look at my answer to SO Question "[Setting timeout for IBM MQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040817/setting-timeout-for-ibm-mq/41456301#41456301)".  The same items apply to XMS as in my question.  You would need to understand how XMS obtains the HBINT value to set this.

Comment: Thank you.  I had a look at your answer. I'm, using Asynchronous message receivers employing MessageListener; so not sure on passsing  the said MQGetMessageOptions.
Does the said timeout also applicable, in the context of using MessageListener to receive messages asyncronously?

Comment: I think you may be referring to Sashi's answer.  This would not apply to Asyncronouse message receivers.  I was referring to my answer about adjusting the HBINT to shorten the time that it takes the MQ client to notice a network disconnect.  I have not had time to research, but since XMS is based on JMS I would guess that the HBINT would also use what is defined on the SVRCONN channel with XMS as well.