# IBM MQ Error 2009 - How to detect when Queue Manager seems to spin up its own thread

Tags: ibm-mq

This is bizarre and somewhat worrying for reliable messaging. I'm hoping I'm missing something.

This has only come to light today due to known network failures. It's giving me a good opportunity to have a look at some fault tolerance.

On thread 1, we send a message on a Queue managed by a Queue Manager. This code:

```
using (MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(_queueManager, _connectionProperties))
{
 // send message
}
```

Just "hangs" on the Queue Manager. As in, it seems to run and then timesout. Maybe it runs on a thread and the thread crashes.

We wouldn't have known anything except we have a second thread listening to another queue.

We have the same construct on the receive thread:

```
using (MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(_queueManager, _connectionProperties))
{
 // listen for message
}
```

But this throws an `MQException` with error code 2009. This suggests a network issue. (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21472342)

However, again, the `QueueManager` on the second thread seems to spin up its own thread on which the exception is thrown, resulting in no ability to catch it and react.

Is there something we're missing?

---

**Update**

Here are my connection properties:

```
Hashtable connectionProperties = new Hashtable();
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.USE_MQCSP_AUTHENTICATION_PROPERTY, true);
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channel);
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, portNumber);
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT_Q_MGR);
return connectionProperties;
```

Bearing in mind I am a novice at IBM MQ, I notice that I have the connection property `MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT_Q_MGR`. Will this play a role? I'm aiming for knowing and managing when things go wrong as opposed to relying on something we don't entirely understand.

Comment: What mq version on the app side?

Comment: It's not clear what you have set for connection properties. Are you using automatic re-connection?

Comment: @JoshMc We're using the 8.0.0.7.

Comment: @Shashi I've added Connection Properties to the question. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks. As you have set reconnect option, MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT_Q_MGR, the MQ .NET client is possibly attempting to reconnect to the queue manager when a connection to queue manager is broken. By default the reconnection attempts are made for 30 minutes. If not successful, it times out.

Comment: @Shashi - Ah, thanks for filling me in. Though that option looks like it is NO_reconnect I see what you mean. I've tried removing that (it is important I know ASAP that there is a problem) and behaviour remains. I don't get told that the Queue Manager is unavailable. Also this https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.0.1/com.ibm.mq.amqzag.doc/fa70190_.htm says that the .NET client doesn't support auto-reconnection anyway.

Comment: Are there any FDC files on the MQ server side? I had a similar strange problem with MQRC 2009 using MQ 8.0.0.8; the FDC file helped me to identify that I ran into an know problem fixed with APAR IT23364.

Comment: @DanielSteinmann Thanks Daniel. Unfortunately we don't have access to the server. The reason for the disconnection is known and expected and the MQ team aren't available to investigate at the moment.

Comment: Note that detecting when the queue manager disconnecting because of a server/queue manager crash or network issue is based on the HBINT (Heart Beat Interval).  Look at my answer to StackOverflow question "[Setting timeout for IBM MQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040817/setting-timeout-for-ibm-mq/41456301#41456301)" for more detail on how the HBINT impacts the TIMEOUT of a client channel.

Comment: Note2: The IBM  Knowledge center which states that a .Net client that is not using a CCDT will negotiate the HBINT that is defined on the queue manager `SVRCONN` channel, this would be accomplished by the .Net client setting it's client side HBINT to an initial value of 1, then negotiating up to the higher SVRCONN value. I have a PMR open with IBM right now because contrary to the KC it does not work this way and instead sets the initial client side HBINT to 300.

Comment: Note2 continued: This means that currently if you want to have a HBINT less than 300 you need to use a CCDT.  If IBM decides to consider this a defect, then a APAR would be generated that would be included in a future version.

Comment: Also just for reference the MQCNO stands for MQ Connection Options.